# Quick Text functionality

Tags: liveagent

I am trying to set up the Quick Text, this feature goes along with the Live Agent but in order to get we need to get the "new" Developer Edition version as of 14 June 2012.

My issue is that I have followed all the instructions from this doc (as per the link below): https://emea.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/live_agent_impl_guide.pdf
but when trying to type a text nothing appear.
Is that normal because it is a Developer Edition or am I still missing something?

Thank you in avdvance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to type ;; (i.e., semi-colon semi-colon) in the chat window to prompt the quick text as [documented here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=case_interaction_using_quick_text.htm&language=en_US).

[image: Live Agent Quick Text]

Also, make sure that the agent has access to the record (org wide defaults,  sharing, etc.) and that the Quick Text record(s) are assigned to the Live Agent channel.

Comment: Yeees it is now working. Thanks for this. Pity that it was not specified on the implementation guide. Cheers,
Sandrine

Comment: @SandrineForce - I converted your answer to a comment. It's good etiquette here to 'accept' the answer if it works - click the green 'tick' by the answer score.